# How can I chain Promise functions with dynamic length?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have variable count of data in an array. I want something, to do this:

```
function tryThis(num: number): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    if(num == 3){
      resolve()
    }else{
      reject();
    }
  }
}

let arrayOfSomething : Array<number> = [1,2,3,4];
let chain;

// create the chain
arrayOfSomething.forEach( (element) => {
    // add element to the chain
    chain.catch(() => {
      tryThis(element);
    });
});


// run chain
chain
  .then(() => {
    // one of elemnts of the array was 3
  })
  .catch(() => {
    // no "3" found in array
  })
```

So, my goal is to create a Promise chain form an array with variable count of data and at the end catch if all of tryThis() function gives reject. If one of tryThis() function gives resolve in the chain, then jump to the end and exit with resolve.

I know, that my code is not correct, this is just to show what I want to do.

Can anyone help me, to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want use Promise for this? `tryThis` is not async function.

Comment: Because tryThis() is just an example. I want later us async function 
instead of tryThis().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybee you could use [Promise.any](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.any.html) from bluebird, or similar functionality from some other library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise.any or https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-any.

`Promise.any` is rejected if all elements are rejected. So, from array of numbers you need to create array of promises, and then call `Promise.any`. So for example:

```
let arrayOfSomething = [1,2,3,4];
Promise.any(arrayOfSomething.map(x => tryThis(x))
  .then(() => {
    // one of elemnts of the array was 3
  })
  .catch(() => {
    // no "3" found in array
  })
```

Comment: In this solution running the tryThis() functions paralell? Because this is not good for me. It is important, to run all function in series, like a simple promise chain.

I try this solution, but seems not work for me.